# How to get previous characters in string

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, visual-studio, char

I am creating a function that will allow me to get the previous character in a string during a for loop .

```
Private Sub TSButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TSButton.Click
    For Each ch As Char In HTextDisplay.Text
        MsgBox("the previous characters here")
        'carry out function here
    Next
End Sub
```

so if `HTextDisplay.Text` is "ABCDEFG" then the msgbox will show "A" then "B" then "C" .....

on the other hand I may be better if i could just check if there is a character behind the character in the function of the for loop

Comment: what do you mean with 'previous'? In your ABCDE sample you just access one after the other.

Comment: if HTextDisplay.Text is "ABCDEFG" then the mesgbox will show "A" then "B" then "C" .....if  the current character in the loop is B, C, D respectivly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dim previousChar as char = ""
For Each ch as Char in HTextDisplay.Text
    msgbox ch & " - previous character = " & previousChar
    'other processing
    previouschar = ch
Next
```